# Installing Kernel Headers

Tags: linux-headers

I have built, installed, and am now running a recent 4.18.0-rc1+ kernel from kernel.org on a Xubuntu machine. The machine used to run 4.13.0-45. I am now trying to compile programs against it with gcc and I am encountering issues with my kernel headers being out of date. I want to use the new mmap DAX flags.

I have successfully built the kernel headers with 'make headers_install' and I have them sitting in a folder in my home. Do I need to put these somewhere so gcc sees them by default? Should I point gcc to the new headers for this program only? How?